# Projection of vector onto a shorter vector allowed?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

After seeing the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064465/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-product-and-the-scalar-projection) by @Vijay P R I. It was my understanding that the dot product $\vec a \cdot \vec b=|\vec a||\vec b|\cos\theta$ will always return the *same* result regardless of whether we choose to project $\vec a$ onto $\vec b$ or $\vec b$ onto $\vec a$.

[image: Projection of b onto a]

What happens if the projection of one of the vectors is *longer* than the other vector itself? Is the projection of $\vec b$ onto $\vec a$ still $|\vec b|\cos\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because  the projection of $\mathbf b$ is not onto $\mathbf a$ but **on the direction** of $\mathbf a$ ( you can also think to an angle $\theta >90°$).